# Conditional Formatting from cells in adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[inventory sheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLDo8Up_RJa2rXsEZ9ElKBEhGUTsMw61-fQspOPuBz4/edit#gid=0)

I'm trying to conditionally format column E based on column D. For example, if the value in column D is <8, highlight the adjacent cell in column E green. If value is >7 and <15, highlight yellow. If value is >14, highlight red.

The formula I have now works, but I can't figure how to apply the formatting to the entire column without manually inputting 3+ conditional format rules on each individual cell.

Answer (score 1):

The existing conditional format from your sheet is partially correct, it just needs some tweaking on the `Apply to range` value. You can create 3 conditional formats on `E3` and it will apply to the whole column of `E` if you put the `E3:E` on range.

Please see the 3 conditional formats I have created based from your given sheet.

### Conditional format 1:

[image]

### Conditional format 2:

[image]

### Conditional format 3:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[AND function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the whole range and create one single rule per condition. Use the formula as it is created for the first cell and it will "drag" automatically.

For example with `=D2>15`

[image]